# Left navigation bar on pages

Tags: navigation, development

Can anyone help with a design query, We currently developing a website using magento 1.9 and we have the basic category's across the top of the pages as standard, we are now looking to add a category box down the left side of every page but as well as keeping the top category box too. We have found code and addons but this seems to replace the top cat box with the side one and we would like to have both

Can anyone help with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lot of options available for this functionality

You can use following extensions

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sidebar-navigation-menu-professional.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-sidebar-navigation-2.html

**Recommended :** https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sidebar-navigation-menu-professional.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, will these still keep the bar at the top of the page though as well? As we are looking for both, and it seemed when we looked at those before it removed the bar from the top? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it will keep the top menu bar on the page. I have worked with this recommended extension before. you can make adjustment for left bar from admin settings.